# How to create a PostgreSQL index that includes Latitude/Longitude (using GIST), but also regular fields

Tags: postgresql, indexing, earthdistance

I have a table of locations that users of my app need to be able to search in. Baically "locations within x miles of me"

I'm using a query like this:

```
select * from job_locations 
   where earth_box(ll_to_earth(51.5, -0.085), 5000) @> ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)  
   and earth_distance(ll_to_earth(51.5, -0.085), ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude)) < 5000;
```

And an index like this:

```
CREATE INDEX job_locations_lat_lng on job_locations USING gist(ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude));
```

However, this is a multi-tenant system, where all tables have a "tenant_id" field, and we *always* filter by that too. So ideally, I'd be able to have both tenant_id and ll_to_earth(lat, lng) in the index, which should presumably make searching much faster.

Is this possible? How do I create that index?

Thanks!
Daniel

Comment: Quick question, is `gist(ll_to_earth()` a spatial index or a generic index of postgres?

Comment: @MortezaShahriariNia it's a generic index of Postgres.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably need the [btree_gis](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/btree-gist.html)t extension to create the index to include the tenant_id field, which appears to have existed since at least Postgres 8,.4.

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE INDEX job_locations_lat_lng ON job_locations USING gist(tenant_id, ll_to_earth(latitude, longitude));
```

Comment: Excellent, adding that extension fixed the problem. Thank you!!

Comment: Quick question, is `gist(ll_to_earth()` a spatial index or a generic index of postgres?

Comment: "ll_to_earth()" is part of the "earthdistance" module, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/earthdistance.html.
  
"gist" is an index type in core PostgreSQL, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-indexes.html