# Choosing the correct DB type

Tags: postgresql, azure, azure-postgresql

I have to create a DB which has around 130 million records which is around 90GB when loaded. I want to host this in the azure. DB modifications will happen once a day as a batch operation. Searching has to be done more often which should return the results within 2 seconds. Search includes text search (address) and a few other numerical fields.

I'm trying to figure out the most cost effective database but providing above mentioned performance. I've tested Single server PostgreSQL DB but the performance is terrible even after I added

```
General Purpose Gen-5 4 cores (20GB RAM) and 500GB storage (1500 IOPS).
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE properties(
    PropertyId bigint,
    Address text,
    Latitude double precision,
    Longitude double precision,
    Rooms int,
    BathRooms int
)
```

indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX address_idx ON properties USING GIN (Address gin_trgm_ops);
CREATE INDEX propertyid_idx ON properties(PropertyId);
CREATE INDEX latitude_idx ON properties(Latitude);
CREATE INDEX longitude_idx ON properties(Longitude);
```

sample query:

```
select * from my_table 
where Latitude between x and y
and Longitude between p and q
and address like '%address%';
```

Analysis:

```
"Bitmap Heap Scan on properties  (cost=34256.04..34901.54 rows=10 width=561) (actual time=24664.562..32007.752 rows=35 loops=1)"
"  Recheck Cond: ((Address ~~ '%3365%'::text) AND (Longitude >= '-90.5'::double precision) AND (Longitude <= '-90'::double precision))"
"  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 1123"
"  Filter: ((propertylatitude >= '38'::double precision) AND (propertylatitude <= '39'::double precision))"
"  Rows Removed by Filter: 64"
"  Heap Blocks: exact=1213"
"  Buffers: shared hit=181 read=6478"
"  I/O Timings: read=31160.388"
"  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=34256.04..34256.04 rows=161 width=0) (actual time=24660.058..24660.059 rows=0 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=169 read=5277"
"        I/O Timings: read=23836.224"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on address_idx  (cost=0.00..135.75 rows=12233 width=0) (actual time=6892.077..6892.077 rows=12973 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: (Address ~~ '%3365%'::text)"
"              Buffers: shared hit=168 read=321"
"              I/O Timings: read=6815.544"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on longitude_idx  (cost=0.00..34120.04 rows=1627147 width=0) (actual time=17763.265..17763.265 rows=1812752 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((Longitude >= '-90.5'::double precision) AND (Longitude <= '-90'::double precision))"
"              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=4956"
"              I/O Timings: read=17020.681"
"Planning Time: 0.267 ms"
"Execution Time: 32008.085 ms"
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please add the description of your table with indeces, the SQL you execute, EXPLAIN ANALYZE result.

Comment: @JuliusTuskenis question updated with more info

Comment: I think you will find this question interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18059740/how-to-create-a-postgresql-index-that-includes-latitude-longitude-using-gist

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how your DB is structured nor the QUERY you are using, so take my answer with a grain of salt until you provide more context.

[ElastricSearch](https://www.elastic.co/), while not exactly a DB, would prove useful for your use case (if I understood correctly the issue you are dealing with).

Comment: I've added more info to the question

Comment: Thank you. I'd still suggest giving ElasticSearch a try.